# How to obtain first 5 values from a LinkedHashSet?

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop, linkedhashset

I have a LinkedHashSet which contains multiple number of values.

```
LinkedHashSet<String> lhs = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
```

I want to iterate through the set of values and display the first five values from the number of items stored in the set. I have used a for loop to iterate through values and display data, see below:

```
for (String sent : lhs) {        
    text.append(sent);                                          
}
```

This outputs all the values stored in the LinkedHashSet. What alterations should I make to my code in order to only get the first 5 values from the set.

Comment: How about breaking the loop after 5 iterations (controlled by `int` variable)?

Comment: This depends on what version of Java you are using... With Java 7- the solution for this would be vastly different from what it would be with Java 8+. Also, you say you want the 5 first values: in what? A collection, an array?

Comment: @fge android uses Java 7

Comment: @Mussa no it doesn't. Android, as far as I know, still doesn't have any viable JSR 203, or JSR 292, implementation

Comment: Can you please define "values"? You `.append()` to some `text` but do not even tell what this `text` is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
for (String sentences : lhs) {       
    if (i > 4) break; 
    text.append(sentences);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. This is exactly the type of solution that I was trying to figure out.

Comment: @coder and what is supposed to happen if the input set has _less elements_ than what you are waiting for?

Comment: @fge it would still work because it only stops if it is greater than 4.

Comment: @fge it will stop if *i* is greater than 4 **or** if *lhs* runs out of items

Answer (score 6):

You can get your sets `Iterator`

```
Iterator<String> it = yourSet.iterator();
```

and move to `next()` element N times (assuming that it still `hasNext()` element)

```
int counter = 0;
while(it.hasNext() && counter++ < N){
    String element = it.next();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'd make it a `for` loop.

Comment: @Arrvi Meh, that's really a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Arrvi why? This ultimately has no influence on the final result

Comment: Meh, a `for` loop is really just a fancy way of saying a `while` loop. :P

Comment: It "hides" the _counter_ variable.

Answer (score 5):

If you had **java8**, then I would suggest something like this:

```
yourLinkedHashSet
    .stream()
    .limit(5)
    .forEachOrdered(text::append);
```

Explanation:

- `stream()` will take one String after another from the collection
- `limit(5)` will stop the calculations after five elements are processed
- `forEachOrdered(...)` takes an action for each item, one after another
- `text::append` is the action to be done per item

Comment: Thanks. @slartidian Why not use forEach instead?

Comment: @Khanna111 For me the stream syntax reflects more the intent. To me it is easier to read and understand. I however am aware, that this is subjective and might be different for others.

Comment: Sorry not clear. I meant why use forEachOrdered instead of forEach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use subList without counter declaration

```
  Iterator<String> iter = new ArrayList<>(lhs).subList(5, lhs.size())
    .iterator();
  while (iter.hasNext()) {
    text.append(iter.next());
  }
```